# kibana how to visualize cache hits and misses?

Tags: kibana

[image]

Hi, I'm new to kibana visualize.

## Background

I want to visualize cache hit ratio of api response.

- when it's a hit I log ...: “<url…> <some info…> USING CACHE”
- what it's a miss I log...: “<url …> <some info…> NO HIT”

## Query

I made two Y-Axis (picture below) but two graphs are same...

## Question

How do I show cache hits and misses in one graph?
Do I have to add a new filter? or X-Axies?

Comment: I'm not on kibana right now, but you should be able to filter each Y-axis independently. If you still struggle, I will post a proper answer.

Comment: @dcolazin please! show me the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember wrongly the options about the Y-axis in the aggregation based visualizations. You can build those kind of visualizations both with TSVB and Aggregation Based viz.

With TSVB you just select the index pattern in the panel options (you can also restrict the documents searched with a Kibana query in the "panel filter")

[image]

In the data section you can build two filter metrics: in the example "error" and "warn", but in your case you can produce a "hit" metric with query string `content: "USING CACHE"` and similarly with a "miss" metric with `content: "NO HIT"`

[image]

If you instead want to use an aggregation based visualization like in your screenshot, you can split the series like in the following example

[image]